# How do specify string format C#

Tags: c#

I have ID as 10 digits int ex: 1023456789 and I need to set DataGridView format to have there `"102-34567 add. 89"`.

`string.Format("###-##### add. ##")` doesn't work.
So how to do that?

Comment: Is the original data actually a number or is it a `string`?

Comment: `String.Format` works. It's job is to to format a non-string value as a string. It doesn't work with string inputs, nor is it meant to. What did you actually try?

Comment: Assuming it actually is a number, you simply assign the format specifier to the `DefaultCellStyle.Format` property of the column. You don't call `String.Format` yourself. The grid calls `ToString` on the data and passes the format specifier that you provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var result = 1023456789.ToString("###-##### add\\. ##");
```

Comment: This is for a `DataGridView` though, so there should not be any `String.Format` or `ToString` call at all.

Comment: You could do it in the CellFormatting event if you wanted to. In any case the format string would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If the `ID length is always 10` characters,you can use [String.Insert(Int32, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.insert?view=net-7.0)

```
 string s = "1023456789";
 string resultt = s.Insert(3, "_").Insert(9, " add. "); //"102-34567 add. 89"
```

Comment: This won't work if the input is actually a 10-digit int. It won't work with a DataGridView at all